# Disputed answer and request for edit

Tags: discussion

I recently answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33119092/2291321) which had a simple enough answer so provided an example command to use on the command line.

However, the OP seems to have taken umbrage over the fact that the exact example command I used doesn't work for them (it specifies an inventory file that they don't have) and attempted to edit the question to remove this argument.

That edit was rejected by other reviewers so the OP has since [reposted my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33136779/2291321) with the change that they wanted.

As I've mentioned in the comments, I feel that the change isn't warranted and is actually slightly less clear for future readers of the answer.

Should I have simply made the requested change even though I disagree with the necessity of it?

His/her answer clearly references my own and why they have created it so it doesn't strike me as plagiarism but I'm not convinced it adds anything to the question/answer combo as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I would've *added* the OP-specific code to the answer.
(So, have both versions in your answer.)

These [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9848593) [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9849589) were completely unacceptable, though. They were rightly rejected. The OP's [reaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119092/how-to-prompt-user-for-a-target-host-in-ansible/33136779#comment54085413_33136779) to the rejection, on his own answer is quite poor:

> *"This is the right answer to my question. It is inspired by the answer of ydaetskcoR, but I have had enough fighting incompetent reviewers to get the example command working and universal (or at least working in OP's, that is my, environment). I managed to fix some of the mistakes author made, but not all, I asked for a correction, but was denied"*.

This has now been flagged as "unconstructive".

Comment: That's a good point actually. I edited my answer to include the missing inventory argument and explained when that would be useful.